# Vlookup from multiple source

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

This doesn't error, it just gives me "FALSE" as a result.  I'm thinking I can't do a vlookup from two different sources, but want to verify?  If not, suggestions for an alternative?  Thanks!

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A69),"",IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A69,sheets!J:J,1,FALSE)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A69,Lines!B:B,1,FALSE)),"No Match",IF(VLOOKUP(A69,sheets!J:J,1,FALSE),"Matches sheet",IF(VLOOKUP(A69,Lines!B:B,1,FALSE),"Line","No Match")))))
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback!  I'm testing a few of your suggestions to see if they get me any closer.  I should have added that the result should be on one sheet or the other, not both.  However, due to low data quality I'm working with, I have to do an actual search of both worksheets instead of defaulting to a false than just assume "if false, then should be true" or visa versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which do you want to check first? Perhaps try MATCH as you only seem to want to verify the presence of a match, i.e.

`=IF(A69="","",IF(ISNA(MATCH(A69,sheets!J:J,0)),IF(ISNA(MATCH(A69,Lines!B:B,0)),"No Match","Line"),"Matches sheet"))`

That will show "Matches sheet" if A69 is found in **both** sheets, if you don't want that then reverse the order of the MATCHES/text.

...or use COUNTIF

`=IF(A69="","",IF(COUNTIF(sheets!J:J,A69),"Matches Sheet",IF(COUNTIF(Lines!B:B,A69),"Line","No Match")))`

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably be better off doing each lookup in separate cell across the row. You could also use MATCH rather than VLOOKUP. There shouldn't be a problem with what you are doing other then incorrect nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to drop the ISNA tests and instead try wrapping all of your VLOOKUPS in NOT(ISERROR(...)).  The formula I got is:

```
  =IF(ISBLANK(A69),"",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A69,sheets!J:J,1,FALSE))),IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A69,Lines!B:B,1,FALSE))),"No Match",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A69,sheets!J:J,1,FALSE))),"Matches sheet",IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A69,Lines!B:B,1,FALSE))),"Line","No Match")))))
```

This formula produced a result of "Matches sheet" in my very limited test. You should check whether it produces the result(s) you are looking for with your data set.